# android - Поймать нажатие вне диалогового окна

Tags: android

Например, мне нужно показать окно, но выполнять какие-то действия, когда пользователь кликает либо вне области этого окна, либо нажимает на кнопку `Back`. Ставить `setCanselable(false);` - не вариант. Нужно оставить возможность закрыть окно, но поймать нажатие вне него.

Может есть какой-нибудь `OnCanselableListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть у диалоговых окон метод `setOnDismissListener()`, устанавливающий слушатель события исчезновения диалога с экрана

Comment: Спасибо) Буду знать) Спросил просто так)